# DioErrorType.RESPONSE: Http status error [500] (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to post image and data but I'm getting this error plz help.
  I'm using dio: ^3.0.9.
  Works perfectly fine in postman And if I remove the image from data and post just the data it works fine.

```
class ProfileRepository {
  LocalStorage localStorage = new LocalStorage();
  Dio dio = new Dio();

  final url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/profile';

  Future<ProfileModel> getProfileResponse(
      String fullName,
      String position,
      String gender,
      String homeAddress,
      String officeAddress,
      String phoneNumber,
      File image) async {
    final token = await localStorage.getLoginToken();
    final splitToken = token.split(' ');
    final finalToken = splitToken[1];

    String imageFile = image.path.split('/').last;
    var formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "fullname": fullName,
      "position": position,
      "gender": gender,
      "home_address": homeAddress,
      "office_address": officeAddress,
      "phone_no": phoneNumber,
      "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path, filename: imageFile),
    });

    final response = await dio.post(url,
        data: formData,
        options: Options(headers: {'Authorization': finalToken}));

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return ProfileModel.fromJson(json.jsonDecode(response.data));
    } else {
      throw Exception("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/profile';

  Future<ProfileModel> getProfileResponse(
      String fullName,
      String position,
      String gender,
      String homeAddress,
      String officeAddress,
      String phoneNumber,
      File image) async {
    final token = await localStorage.getLoginToken();
    final splitToken = token.split(' ');
    final finalToken = splitToken[1];

    String imageFile = image.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData() {
     var formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "fullname": fullName,
      "position": position,
      "gender": gender,
      "home_address": homeAddress,
      "office_address": officeAddress,
      "phone_no": phoneNumber,
    });
      formData.files.addAll([
          MapEntry(
              "files",
              MultipartFile.fromFileSync(image.path, filename: imageFile)),
      ]);
      return formData;
    }
    final response = await dio.post(url,
        data: formData(),
        options: (contentType: 'multipart/form-data', headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": finalToken,
      }),
    ););

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return ProfileModel.fromJson(json.jsonDecode(response.data));
    } else {
      throw Exception("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

Try this. If I had to guess, I think it's issue with your image path.

Comment: Edited the code. Try and see if that works. If it doesn't, either your database endpoint is not configured to receive file properly "i.e. extension error/ mime type error" or your image path is incorrect. I had the same issue and it turned out to be invalid mime type configured on the server. Worked on postman for me as well.